# Should I connect my 2nd monitor to integrated or discrete graphics to maximize 3D performance on the 1st monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, performance, integrated-graphics, discrete-graphics

I have 2 monitors connected to my PC, and the secondary monitor is used for things that don't really need the power of a discrete GPU. I want to maximize the performance of 3D applications on my primary monitor. Would connecting the secondary monitor to integrated graphics instead of the discrete GPU increase the performance of applications running on the primary monitor compared to connecting both to the discrete GPU?

Do I need to take any extra steps to ensure the GPU doesn't take over for integrated graphics if the secondary monitors gets any windows with higher-than-usual graphics requirements? Are there any special considerations, like (this is just a hypothetical example) exclusive fullscreen being more efficient in this setup (as opposed to borderless windowed mode)?

The hardware in question is Intel HD Graphics 4600 and a GeForce 770.

Comment: Many mainboards will not allow you to run off the integrated graphics adapter while you are using an external card. Have you tried it out first?

Comment: @sebleblanc yes, it works.